# On ReactJS, my 'root' div doesn't span all the way up. How can I expand it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, root

I know it is a subject that has been brought many times. However, all the solutions I've tried didn't work and I'm coming here as last resort.

Where my root div stops:

[image: where my root div stops]

I have set the html and body CSS style to be:

```
html, body { height: 100%;   width: 100%; }
```

in my index.css. It still does not go all the way up.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html, body { height: 100%;   width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

**Update:**

I checked your page and found the problem. When the inner elements have margin, the outer element gets affected too. Remove the margin-top of the navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but no, it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to be a question of margin or padding. At least they don't show when I inspect the html.

Comment: @RyanAbi-Sleiman what do you exactly want from your root div? to fill the entire screen?

Comment: that is exactly what I want. For now I just have this annoying gap on top of the screen

Comment: sorry for the late answer! I was busy at work. Anyway, I've created a git repo and made it public if you want to see it. The website is not up yet. Thanks for the help :)
Running npm install and npm start should do the trick to see it on localhost. If it's too much work, I understand
https://github.com/gryanab/cpm-paris-bis

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it solves your problem.